# How do I incorporate a variable into a range-reference

Tags: vba, excel

I store a number in a variable `a`, like this:

```
a = Worksheets("MySheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

How do I incorporate this value in a Range-function in Excel-VBA? If `a` for instance holds 3, how do I use it to refer to Range("A3")?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the below will use the value in a

```
range("A" & a)

Cells(a,1)
```

If you wanted to use it in a range you could do something like

```
range("A1:A" & a )
```

Comment: Could mark some of your questions(all 6 of them?) as complete?

Comment: You need 15 to vote up. not mark it as the answer, under the up/down vote arrows there should be a tick box?